# Getting error while updating records nodejs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using update query to modify my records. But when records are exceeding limit like 100 it is not updating record and giving error.
If it is less than 100 it is working fine.
Any suggestion?

Comment: May be related to the options you're passing with `mongoose` check https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#options

Comment: @Minsky  Error is:
(node:9036) DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.
error MongoError: Error=16500, RetryAfterMs=20, Details='Batch write error.

I have tried UpdateMany as well.

Comment: use `updateMany`

Comment: I have tried that as well